# Search and filter Dictionary in json file with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Am trying to test if could fetch a json file which contains thousands of words and then auto-search with them ng-filter like below. Yes, i get my dictionary displayed like it should but it doesn't get filtered when i start typing.

list.html

```
  <section>
    <form action="/" >
      <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="search" ng-model="search">
    </form>

   <p ng-repeat="(k, v) in dictionary | filter:search ">
     {{k}}: {{v}}
   </p>
  </section>
```

app.js

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
     app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 
        function($scope, $http){
     $http.get('dictionary.json').success(function(data){
     $scope.posts = data;
   }]);
```

json file(dictionary.json)

```
 {
    "achieve": "zustandebringen",
    "confident": "zuversichtlich",
    "thoughtfulness": "Zuvorkommenheit",
    "twenty": "zwanzig",
    "twentieth": "zwanzigste",
    "two": "zwei",
    "two equal parts": "zwei gleiche Teile",
    "twice": "zweimal",
    "twenty-two": "zweiundzwanzig",
    "twenty-second": "zweiundzwanzigste",
    "pinch": "zwicken",
    "among": "zwischen",
    "amongst": "zwischen",
    "between": "zwischen",
    "between two persons": "zwischen zwei Personen",
    "twelve": "zwölf",
    "twelfth": "zwölfte"
  }
```

Please any assistance?

Answer (score 0):

Angular filters can only be applied to arrays and not **[objects](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)**, from angular's API

You can create a custom filter and apply the filter

**Filter:**

```
 app.filter('Find', function() {
  return function(input, str) {
    var tmp = {};
    angular.forEach(input, function(val, key) {
      if (val.indexOf(str) !== -1) {
        tmp[key] = val;
      }
    });
    return tmp;
  };
})
```

**HTML:**

```
   <p ng-repeat="(k, v) in dictionary  | Find: search||'' ">
        {{k}}: {{v}}
   </p>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/qn1A79CXqZTcCAimQW6d?p=preview)**